# what is that: Content-Type: application/x-bxml?

Tags: xml, http, xml-parsing, content-type

I've recently discovered one public undocumented web service that I would like to use.
The Problem is in Content Type that is used by the web serivice.
Content-Type: application/x-bxml

What is that?
At first sight it looks like Binary Xml,I am able to recognize xml tags and attribute names, but I cannot find any description for the format.

The header of the data starts with "BXMLe".

any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will have to contact the people who provide the web service. This is not a standard content-type.

Comment: I am aware that this is a not one of the standart content types... but they are not going to share this information. This is why I have asked the community.

Answer (score 0):

BXML is an XML-based markup language for simplifying the construction of Java object hierarchies. While it is most often used to define the user interface of an Apache Pivot application, it is not limited to user interface construction, and can actually be used to create hierarchies of any object type.

http://pivot.apache.org/tutorials/bxml-primer.html